# Getting TypeError when using the sum function in Python

Tags: python, function, sum

What am I doing wrong to get this error using the `sum` function in Python:

```py
student_heights =input("Input a list of student heights ").split()
a=sum(student_heights)
print(a)
```

User input: `12 13 14 15`

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
TypeError unsupported operand type(s) for +:'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: `student_heights` is a list of *strings*. You can't  `sum()` them usefully until you convert them to integers.  This will work but depends on error-fee input: `a=sum(int(h) for h in student_heights)`.

Answer (score 2):

The elements in your list are strings (that's how they return from `input()` from the console). You can, for example, convert them to integers:

```
a = sum(int(element) for element in student_heights)
```

Then you can sum them.

Answer (score 0):

your variable student_heights is a type of list. A list accept string values. So we need to iterate through the list.

```
student_heights = input("Input a list of student heights ").split()
a = sum(int(i) for i in student_heights)
print(a)
```